# Magento 1.9.2.1 Column not found

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a issue with Magento 1.9.2.1. When trying to view a page after clicking a sub menu, I get this error message (not full error message):

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.min_price'
>   in 'field list', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id),
>   ROUND(MAX(e.min_price -(e.min_price/(1+(CASE e.tax_class_id WHEN 2
>   THEN ...

Trace:

```
0 /home/foo/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
1 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
2 /home/foo/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
3 /home/foo/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
4 /home/foo/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
5 /home/foo/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
6 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(935): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array, 3)
7 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(2129): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->_prepareStatisticsData()
8 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(139): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->getMaxPrice()
9 /home/foo/public_html/app/design/frontend/buyshop/default/template/ajax/price_slider.phtml(3): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getMaxPriceInt()
10 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/foo/...')
11 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/buysho...')
12 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
13 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
14 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
15 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
16 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
17 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
18 /home/foo/public_html/app/design/frontend/buyshop/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(65): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
19 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/foo/...')
20 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/buysho...')
21 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
22 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
23 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
24 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
25 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
26 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
27 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
28 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
29 /home/foo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
30 /home/foo/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
31 /home/foo/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('instbutik...', 'website')
32 {main}
```

I have tried to re-index the database from the admin console and flush the cache. Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

The problem occurred after an update from an earlier version of Magento.

Comment: Which page are you referring to?

Comment: Probably an issue with an extension that is not compatible with 1.9 - to say more, one would need at least the full error message including its stack trace.

Comment: This looks like a normal query for price data on the flat product table. Can you try to reindex from shell and see if it is successful? `php shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Answer (score 1):

May be a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103833/column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-e-min-price-in-field-list but can't be flagged as it is not in magento.stackexchange.com

In the comments you see a screener how the table should look like and that (in this case) the extension Sweet Tooth was the reason. Maybe in your case too?

Check your extensions by disabling them and activate them one by one, check if the extensions are compatible with magento 1.9.2.x, rebuild ALL indexes, including flats.